# How to create multiple index with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have such index

```
Index(
    'ix_table_index',
    func.extract('year', date),
    func.extract('month', date),
    func.extract('day', date),
)
```

As a result I've got index in postgresql table:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_table_index
    ON table USING btree
    (date_part('year'::text, date));
```

`month` and `day` parts are ignored (only first part `year` created)... Why?

Comment: Did you actually solve this? I've arrived to your same implementation and it is working with sqlalchemy's current version. I still need to add the `hour`-part to the index and it seems it is being ignored (like what happened to you with month and day).